# Consulta en rango de fechas y hora mysql

Tags: mysql

nuevamente me encuentro por acá intentando solucionar un problemilla.

Estoy realizando un pequeño sistema para reservas canchas de futbol y padel. Estas canchas puedes ser reservadas por hora (1 o más horas).

Tengo una reserva agregada que es con la fecha "2021-08-11 20:00:00" y salida "2021-08-11 22:00:00". Pero no he logrado ejecutar una consulta que me busque todas las canchas disponibles y no se encuentren lógicamente dentro de ese rango de fechas. He realizado unas consultas, pero se confunde con fecha de salida y me toma como si a las 22 hrs estuviera ocupado y realmente en la reserva es la hora de salida, por ende debería mostrar esa cancha disponible.

Como lo harían ustedes para buscar las canchas disponibles y que no se encuentren en el horario especificado?

Esta es mi base de datos

[image: modelo bd]

Tabla Canchas:

[image: canchas]

Tabla Reservas:

[image: reservas]

Tabla Reservas Canchas (que es la relación entre las canchas y la reserva ya que pueden ser mas de una cancha, para la misma reserva)

[image: canchas_reservas]

Comment: Muéstranos alguna de esas consultas que has intentado

Comment: Ya apague el portátil. Mañana a primera hora las subo. La verdad que son comparaciones <= y >= a los campos fecha in y fecha out. Si no me equicovo le puse un NOT EXIST. Aún así  si tenía las 22 me mostraba la cancha como no disponible y las 22 ya era hora de salida.

Comment: En tus intentos se ve mucho más: como cómo determinas el tipo de chancha que quiere el usuario, las horas disponibles de cada cancha... Suele ser más rápido verlo en el código que preguntar, por eso, entre otras cosas, pedimos los intentos. No hay prisa, cuando puedas dedicarle tiempo...

Comment: Es fundamental que muestres un [repro] de lo que has intentado, y el problema específico que has tenido. Preguntar "como lo harían ustedes para" (...) suena a que querés que te hagamos la tarea, cosa que no hacemos acá :) Por cierto, [no todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).

Comment: Estaba trabajando con la siguiente consulta "SELECT h.id_cancha FROM canchas h WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL FROM reservas_canchas r WHERE r.id_cancha = h.id_cancha AND "2022-08-11 22:00:00" <= r.fecha_out AND "2022-08-11 23:00:00" >= r.fecha_in) ORDER BY h.id_cancha"

Comment: Ciertas veces está consulta me funciona, pero si seleccionó la hora 22 y en la reserva es la hora de salida, no me muestra la habitación disponible.

Comment: También use: SELECT  h.id_cancha, CASE WHEN hr.id_cancha is null THEN 'Disponible' ELSE 'Reservada' END  AS 'Estado' FROM canchas h LEFT JOIN (SELECT h1.id_cancha FROM canchas h1 inner join reservas_canchas r on h1.id_cancha=r.id_cancha WHERE "2022-08-11 22:00:00" BETWEEN r.fecha_in AND r.fecha_out) hr on hr.id_cancha = h.id_cancha;

Comment: Genial, modifica tu pregunta añadiendo estos intentos y el dataset en SQL

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas crear registros para las horas disponibles, deberás determinar desde y hasta cuándo. Suponiendo desde la hora actual hasta las próximas 24 horas:

```
SET @h := str_to_date(left(now(),13),'%Y-%m-%d %H');
SELECT cast( @h:=@h+interval 1 hour as datetime ) fh
  FROM cualquierTabla
  LIMIT 24
```

Hay que cuidar que `cualquierTabla` tenga por lo menos tantos registros como la cantidad de horas (ej. 24) requeridas.

Entonces podrás hacer un LEFT JOIN para ubicar los horarios disponibles. Suponiendo un horario de disponibilidad de 8 a 23 horas:

```
SET @h := str_to_date(left(now(),13),'%Y-%m-%d %H');
SELECT h.fh
  FROM reservas_canchas rc
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT cast( @h:=@h+interval 1 hour as datetime ) fh
                  FROM cualquierTabla
                  LIMIT 24
              ) h
      ON    h.fh not between rc.fecha_in and rc.fecha_out-interval 1 second
        AND hour(h.fh) between 8 and 23;
```

Comment: wow, no pensé que fuera necesario tener un campo con las horas y marcarlas disponible o no. Ya que como tengo más de 1 cancha tendré que crear además las horas para cada cancha en si?

Comment: No; no necesitas crear una tabla, usas lo que se conoce como una *vista en línea*; que al hacer el JOIN con `canchas` (multiplicas) puedes obtener el horario para cada cancha.